# highcharts sum up tooltip {point.y} with a specific number

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts, highcharts-ng

Hello and thanks SO MUCH in advance for any help you might give. I'm trying to sum the {point.y} that's displayed in the tooltip HTML with a number, for example if {point.y} is 100, I want it to be 100+1=101 . but I can't find a way to do so. ( tried {point.y}+1 , but didn't work as its interpreted as HTML and not as a sum operation). Thank you!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pointFormatter` or `formatter` function callback for a tooltip. For example:

```
  tooltip: {
    pointFormatter: function() {
      return `<span style="color:${this.color}">\u25CF</span> ${this.series.name}: <b>${this.y + 1}</b><br/>`
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9ayqdot6/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormatter

Answer (score 0):

As of Highcharts 11 (2023), you can now add logic into formatting strings, using what they call "helpers" in a format that's like Polish Notation. So you could do something like this:

```
"tooltip":{
      "pointFormat":"{add point.y 1}"
   }
```

and if you needed to do additional formatting (like adding a thousands separator), you could put your math logic into a subexpression by wrapping it in parentheses like this:

```
"tooltip":{
      "pointFormat":"{(add point.y 1):,f}"
   }
```

There's a lot of cool stuff you can do with it, like writing your own custom helpers. More info here: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/templating

I prefer this over the callback method because it allows me to store the highcharts config in JSON format, but this may not matter for you.